# How can I securely store EC private key in Android?

Tags: android, security, cryptography

I have a fixed EC private key to sign some message when my app is running. I can't hard code the private key in my code as there are some potential safety issues. So how can I safely store and use the private key in Android?

Comment: What about Android keystore?

Comment: @vojta I can generate a .bks file which contains a private key and certificate using keytool. Android Keystore can load this .bks file with a keystore password. But the keystore password must hard code with plaintext in my code. But I think there is still some potential risks.

Comment: Keystore protects keys from access of another app. It is not ideal, but reasonably safe for some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is actually no way to hide these credentials. 
One common workaround I used to use is to generate the key by code in native layer (C-extension) then compile into `.so` to call from the app through Java JNI wrapper. This seems to hide the actual code in another layer, but I'm sure there will definitely some ways to break this.